# Silverstripe 4 silvershop-core paypal-expr. tax & shipping

Tags: silverstripe, tax, silvershop

With SS4 + silvershop-core + palpal-express:
In the CMS/Catalog/Product -> Pricing i can fill in a Price.

e.g.:  € 12.90  (12,90) meaning the Base price. (= netto = exclusive Tax 15%)

in shop.yml:

```
SilverShop\Model\Order:
  modifiers:
    - 'SilverShop\Model\Modifiers\Shipping\Simple'
    - 'SilverShop\Model\Modifiers\Tax\FlatTax'
```

QUESTIONS:

- Where are Shipping-Costs and FlatTax defined?
- I need to show Prices in brutto (inclusive Tax) on Frontend to the
  Customer. - How?
- On CheckOut it should be like: (Where and how to calculate this?)

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can set the `FlatTax` to be inclusive by adding the following to our `shop.yml` and flushing the site cache:

```
SilverShop\Model\Modifiers\Tax\FlatTax:
  exclusive: false
```

By checking the [src/Model/Modifiers/Tax/FlatTax.php](https://github.com/silvershop/silvershop-core/blob/master/src/Model/Modifiers/Tax/FlatTax.php) we can see what the config settings are for the `FlatTax` class.

We can also change the flat tax rate and the name of the flat tax like so:

```
SilverShop\Model\Modifiers\Tax\FlatTax:
  exclusive: false
  rate: 0.20
  name: 'VAT'
```

By checking the [src/Model/Modifiers/Shipping/Simple.php](https://github.com/silvershop/silvershop-core/blob/master/src/Model/Modifiers/Shipping/Simple.php) we can see what the config settings are for the `Simple` shipping class. We can also change these default settings:

```
SilverShop\Model\Modifiers\Shipping:
  default_charge: 10
  charges_by_country:
    - 'AU': 20
    - 'FR': 15
```

Comment: Thanks 3dgoo! what doesn't work is : name: VAT. No matter with or without quotes. exclusive: false does work. Another question: is it possible to have different taxes for each product? is it possible to define how many items of one product are available and if no product is in stock the product is still visible but not buyable? thanks.sepp.

Comment: Regarding different taxes for each product, I don't know. You would need to look into that and possibly build your own tax modifier. For managing product stock you can use the following module:
 https://github.com/silvershop/silvershop-stock